# Java - Saber si un JButton ha sido presionado

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

Tengo un problema y es que para mi interfaz gráfica creo unos jbuttons a partir de un bucle for. 
Mientras i < 100 entonces
        Crea jbutton que tengan como título apply y añadelo al layout

Los botones me aparecen correctamente, el problema es que tengo que hacer que cuando aprete uno de esos botones en una lista con valores diferentes, uno de esos valores se vea decrementado deacuerdo con su boton asociado, boton 0 decrementa posicion 0 de la list y así sucesivamente. El problema es que no sé como debo poner los action listener ni como saber que botón de los 100 me han presionado ya que poner 100 action listener diferentes a mano y nombrar a cada boton con un nombre a mano y despues comprobar cual de los 100 botones más han presionado con un get action command me parece muy poco óptimo.

Gracias, 
Alex

Comment: Pues igual que a la hora de crear los botones, lo haces con un bucle, a la hora de llamarlos hazlo igual, con otro bucle con las mismas iteraciones. Le pones a cada boton el valor de i 'iterador' por ejemplo -- `btn = new JButton("boton"+i);` y a la hora de llamarlo pues igual pero con `getActionCommand().equals("boton"+i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como añadir **10 Botones en este caso**, con el título de **Apply**, en el cual construimos dentro de un bucle, en el cual establecemos un `setActionCommand("boton"+i);` para a la hora de llamarlos cuando pulsamos dichos botones, sepamos identificarlos correctamente con un condicional if `if (btn.getActionCommand().equals("boton"+i))` dentro de un bucle for con las mismas iteraciones.

También sabremos que botón fue pulsado y cuantas veces hemos pulsado los botones en unos JLabel colocados en diferentes paneles.

**Ejemplo:**

```
public class PulsacionBoton extends JFrame {
    JButton btn;
    JLabel lbl, lblBtnPuls;
    int contador = 0;
    JPanel panelBtn;

    PulsacionBoton() {
        setTitle("Botones varios");
        setBounds(300, 300, 600, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        lbl = new JLabel("Pulsaciones: ");
        lbl.setText("Pulsaciones: " + 0);
        lblBtnPuls = new JLabel("Boton Pulsado: -1");
        panelBtn = new JPanel();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //btn = new JButton("boton"+i);
            btn = new JButton("Apply");
            btn.setActionCommand("boton"+i);
            btn.addActionListener(new Pulsado());

            panelBtn.add(btn);
        }

        JPanel panelLbl = new JPanel();
        panelLbl.add(lbl);

        JPanel panelLblBtn = new JPanel();
        panelLblBtn.add(lblBtnPuls);

        this.getContentPane().add("North",panelLbl);
        this.getContentPane().add("Center",panelBtn);
        this.getContentPane().add("South",panelLblBtn);
    }

    class Pulsado implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource(); //creacion objeto
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (btn.getActionCommand().equals("boton"+i)) {
                    lbl.setText("Pulsaciones: " + ++contador);
                    //lblBtnPuls.setText("Boton Pulsado: "+btn.getText());
                    lblBtnPuls.setText("Boton Pulsado: "+btn.getActionCommand());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PulsacionBoton().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

---

**Resultado:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]